# Putting text together inside a listview column out of a mysql database?

Tags: c#, mysql

I need to be able to change the product inside my database with this program. To do that I need to be able to put them beside each other. How do I do this?

See image.
https://imgur.com/a/0Vy5XaC

I tried to follow a tutorial but I can't really find any...

```
string connectionURL = @"SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=shopkartje;UID=root;PASSWORD=;SslMode=None";


            MySqlConnection connection = null;
            MySqlDataReader rdr = null;

            try
            {
                connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionURL);
                connection.Open();

                string sql = "SELECT * from producten";
                MySqlCommand commando = new MySqlCommand(sql, connection);

                rdr = commando.ExecuteReader();

                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    lvproducten.Items.Add(rdr.GetString("ID"));
                    lvproducten.Items.Add(rdr.GetString("Productnaam"));
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Kan bestand niet openen ");
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
                rdr.Close();
            }
```

So what code is it that puts these next to each other? They need to be clickable for me to be able to change or update it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a ListView in Detail mode you have many columns of data (subitems)

To add in a single call the data for the 'row' you need to prepare an array

```
string[] row = { rdr.GetString("ID"),  rdr.GetString("Productnaam")};
var lvItem= new ListViewItem(row); 
lvproducten.Items.Add(lvItem);
```

To get back the data from the current selected 'row' you subscribe to the SelectedIndexChanged event and look at your row

```
void lvproducten_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (lvproducten.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
    {
        string id = listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text;
        string product = listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[1].Text;
        .... update your textboxes....
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes this does put the text beside each other, but I need to be able to click on Productnaam. By doing this the name and quantity comes in the textbox you can see on the right side of the image. Does anybody know of a way to do this?

Comment: There is a nice tutorial on working with WinForms ListView at this site:https://www.dotnetperls.com/listview In other words, subscribe to ListView_SelectedIndexChanged event, get the first element in the SelectedItems array and use the SubItems array to extract the text from the 'columns'

Comment: It worked! Thank you and all the other people that helped me with this!

Answer (score 0):

Declare ListView with Details view and add two columns, then iterate through loop
and add items

```
lvproducten.View = View.Details;
lvproducten.Columns.Add("ID", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
lvproducten.Columns.Add("Productnaam", 150, HorizontalAlignment.Left);

while (rdr.Read())
            {
                //lvproducten.Items.Add(rdr.GetString("ID"));
                //lvproducten.Items.Add(rdr.GetString("Productnaam"));
                string[] str = new string[1];
                ListViewItem itm;
                str[0] = rdr.GetString("ID");
                str[1] = rdr.GetString("Productnaam")
                itm = new ListViewItem(str);
                lvproducten.Items.Add(itm);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

your on the right track with items.add but each 'item' is a row so you need to add 'sub items' to that row...

```
ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(rdr.GetString("ID"));
item.SubItems.Add(rdr.GetString("Productnaam"));
listView1.Items.Add(item);
```

so in these 3 steps we have firstly created an item, secondly added our first sub item, then finally added it to our list view.

your listview needs to have its property 'View' set to detail but going by your picture you have already done that :)

if you want to add more columns from you database you can simply add more subitems to your code like this...

```
ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(rdr.GetString("ID"));
item.SubItems.Add(rdr.GetString("Productnaam"));
item.SubItems.Add(rdr.GetString("AnotherRow"));
item.SubItems.Add(rdr.GetString("OneMoreForLuck"));
listView1.Items.Add(item);
```

in addition from your comments you would need to set your list view property 'FullRowSelect' to true then us the SelectedIndexChanged event and something like the following...

```
private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            //Set the first textbox 
            textBox1.Text = listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text;
            //Set the second textbox
            textBox2.Text = listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[1].Text;
        }
    }
```